# Apache 2.4 Win32 PHP 5.21 - cURL not working

Tags: php, apache, curl

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Windows 32bit w/PHP 5.21. I need to use curl extension.

I uncommented the line in php.ini:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

and the file is correctly in /ext/

But when I try to use curl I get this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

In phpinfo() cURL module is not loaded.

Anyone can explain me how to make cURL work???
Thank you

Comment: did you restart the webserver ? ... try to type: `php -i | findstr -r "curl"` in command line to check if your php.ini is correct.

Comment: Thank you. The prompt says that php_curl.dll and ssleay32.dll are not intended to be used with windows! And now? Where can I find the right dlls?

Comment: Download a newer version of PHP. The dll is will be shiped with the installation files. If you don't want the newest Version use: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4-ts-VC9-x86 or for the newest version use: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.6-ts-VC11-x86

Comment: I downloaded and installed windows.php.net/download/#php-5.6-ts-VC11-x86 but is giving me the same error! Damn!

Comment: can you post the error in you question pls.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Comment: now I'm using PHP 5.6.10

Comment: no the error / message from the commandline

Comment: Now php -i is not giving any error but in apache error log I still have PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\\Server\\www\\components\\emailtracking\\emailtracking.php on line 26

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80984/discussion-between-v-eigler-and-newbieforever).

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to PHP 5.6.10, re-setting the php.ini and reboot, now cURL seems to work.
Thanks to v.eigler that helped me.